# How to tell Rollbar not to catch certain exception?

Tags: rollbar

Rollbar always catches certain `Exception`. This isn't really an error(in my case). I don't want Rollbar to catch it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the place in your code where the error is thrown, you can set the 'enabled' option to 'false'.

If you're unsure of the place where the error happens or you don't want to suppress all errors, then you can use the checkignore option. The syntax for that option depends on which rollbar SDK you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Most Rollbar maintained SDKs have the ability to invoke a custom callback method usually called `checkIgnore` (or similar). Implement the method and assign it to Rollbar configuration object's similarly named property. In the method implementation check the payload for a trace member and its exception class, if that is the exception you want to omit - return `false`, otherwise return `true`.